# Generated bitmap using bytes size is vary from Original?

Tags: android, bitmap, byte

After converting the bitmap to bytes again generating the bitmap but the size of the bitmap is vary from original to generated.Why?

> Original Bitmap Width :284 Height :139
>
> bitmap sample size factor :2
>
> Converted Image Width :142 Height :69

To convert used the below code :

```
 BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = powerOf2;
        bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgRawBytes, 0, imgRawBytes.length,
                        bitmapOptions);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected  behaviour since you are setting `bitmapOptions.inSampleSize = 2`. In fact, as cleared pointed out in the docs, if `inSampeSize > 1`,  the decoder will subsample the original image.

From the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html):

> If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original
>   image, returning a smaller image to save memory. The sample size is
>   the number of pixels in either dimension that correspond to a single
>   pixel in the decoded bitmap. For example, inSampleSize == 4 returns an
>   image that is 1/4 the width/height of the original, and 1/16 the
>   number of pixels. Any value <= 1 is treated the same as 1. Note: the
>   decoder will try to fulfill this request, but the resulting bitmap may
>   have different dimensions that precisely what has been requested.
>   Also, powers of 2 are often faster/easier for the decoder to honor.